# SharePoint migration on-prem to cloud on existing content

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-on-prem, content-migration, migration

I am interested in migrating SP on prem to cloud, but I have a couple of questions in mind:

If I have a certain SP site on on-prem, and SP site with the same name on cloud (that was independently created not with a previous migration) what will happened with the content, permissions etc. if I decide to migrate the on-prem site to the cloud?

For example, if only certain people could see the site on on-prem, and everyone else could see the site on cloud what will happened with the access after migrating?

If I have a SP list with 10 items in the cloud site, and a list with same name on on-prem with 5 items, will the other ones be deleted in the cloud after migrating?

I am interested how are those things handled?

Comment: How are you migrating the site? Using any tool?

Comment: I haven't decided yet, I'm just thinking about some scenarios like this, will there be any data loss, or what will happened with the permission etc because I already have "same" sites online as I have on prem. How will a migration tool handle this scenario? What is your advice? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide on which migration tool to use, because each has its own disadvantages over another. The SharePoint Migration Tool (from Microsoft) is not very flexible, where you can't selectively migrate over different selective folders or document library, or rename things, or selectively migrate some columns from A to B, and whatnot.

My recommendation is to use Sharegate Desktop, where it offers you wide range of flexibility and it's affordable (in my opinion). I'm not trying to promote Sharegate, just that my past clients always choose that tool.

I'm answering your question assuming you're using [Sharegate](https://sharegate.com/microsoft-migration).

---

*If I have a certain SP site on on-prem, and SP site with the same name on cloud (that was independently created not with a previous migration) what will happened with the content, permissions etc. if I decide to migrate the on-prem site to the cloud?*

It will overwrite, all document libraries, all settings, folders, and files. But you will have dashboard where you could pick the migration granularly down to the file level.

---

*For example, if only certain people could see the site on on-prem, and everyone else could see the site on cloud what will happened with the access after migrating?*

This really depends on how your on-prem was set up. If it was configured using plain SharePoint that authenticates with Active Directory, and your Active Directory is also set up using Azure AD to your SharePoint Online, then you can migrate with just plain settings on Sharegate and all permissions will naturally fall over the same way. If not, you can also selectively replace a user for a user when migrating.

---

*If I have a SP list with 10 items in the cloud site, and a list with same name on on-prem with 5 items, will the other ones be deleted in the cloud after migrating?*

Nope. It might overwrite though, if it found the same file name in the same relative folder path.